# Maximal depth of a decision tree

Tags: cart

Probably this is a very basic question, but is it possible to compute the full depth of a decision tree given the sample size of the training set, number of its categories, and the feature dimension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The absolute maximum depth would be $N - 1$, where $N$ is the number of training samples.  You can derive this by considering that the least effective split would be peeling off one training example per node.

In practice, no sane algorithm would reach this point:

- Most decision tree algorithms I've seen have multiple stopping criteria, including a user-defined depth and a minimum number of data points that it's willing to split on.  For example, [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html)'s algorithm won't split nodes with 10 or fewer observations by default.
- If the tree uses any reasonable splitting criterion, it will almost always split off more than one observation at a time.  That cuts down on the maximum depth pretty dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So, the maximum depth depends strongly on the implmentation and parametrization.

Comment: Right. In most implementations, it's a tunable parameter and the user tries to pick the optimal depth based on cross-validation.

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris "and the user tries to pick the optimal depth based on cross-validation." you mean e.g consider different allowed maximal depths in seperate experiments and then based on results (precision, recall, F) of course crossvalidated (e.g k-fold) decide what maximal depth is reasonable?

Comment: @andi Yes, exactly.